# Normalising parameter scale with fminsearch

Tags: matlab, optimization

I remember reading once in the Matlab documentation about an optimisation algorithm which allowed the user to specify the "scale" of variation expected for each parameter during the search (at least initially).

I can't remember what this function is, but now I am using [`fminsearch`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html) and there is no such option. In fact, I can't even specify parameter bounds, and the documentation states that it takes 5% of the initial guess as a default step (or 25e-5 if 0). Because this seems to be a relative choice to the initial guess, it makes me think that perhaps I should re-normalise my parameters to a suitable scale, in order to indirectly define a suitable step for my optimisation problem.

For example, if I have a parameter which value is on the order of 10e5 but that I would like steps on the order of 100, then I should "divide it" by 500 during optimisation (obviously I would then multiply it when computing the objective function). However this becomes trickier if a parameter range is centred around 0 for example; then I can rescale it and offset it.

My question is; is it effectively what people usually do when using the downhill-simplex method, and is there a "standard" or "better" way to do it?

Comment: Have you looked at `fminbnd` (single variable)? Or, probably more applicable, if you have the optimization toolbox, take a look at `fmincon`.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Thanks for your suggestions. My problem is multivariate (so `fminbnd` is not appropriate), and has a very costly objective function (~5 min to evaluate each sample, so gradient/hessian-based methods like `fmincon` are inappropriate). I didn't think context on this question was necessary, but the point is that I very specifically want to use `fminsearch` in order to compare the results with another method using surrogates.

Comment: 5 minutes!! How large are we talking about?! Is it very data intensive, or...how come it takes so long! If it's a big problem (as in, many dimensions), `fminsearch` is almost certain to take longer converging than `fmincon` will, even with numerical derivatives. Rate of convergence of the Nelder-Mead simplex method is quite terrible for large problems....

Comment: I think it's much more effective if we look together at that objective function;  I'm almost certain we can reduce that cost. Scaling is not really going to have much of an effect; that's usually something you do when great accuracy is required. Unless you enforce step size (in the objective function, by rounding the input to nearest 100), `fminsearch` et al. will simply adjust to the new scale, rendering the operation pretty much  useless after the first step...

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Didn't intend to scare you :) The problem is relatively low-dimensional (<15 dimensions), but the objective function involves solving a large system of nonlinear coupled delay-differential equations over a relatively long time-span. This is done in C++ and the performance is state-of-the-art, so not much hope optimising this further. I expect N-M is sensitive to the initial guess, and I'm therefore providing a sensible one for a fair comparison, but certain parameters vary on the order of 10e2 and others 10e-3, so I want to get that out of the way if relevant and possible.

Comment: hmmm....sounds like a very interesting problem you have there :) just out of curiosity, what kind of problem is this? I mean, neuroscience, obviously, but what specifically? Can I still look at the code, or is it to be kept closed source?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Haha, good guess! :) The neuroscience part of the code is private until my first paper is out, but the C++ core and integration libs (which do the heavy lifting) are on [my github](https://github.com/Sheljohn) if you are interested. Sorry though, I haven't had time to document them at this point.